# Page redirection without reloading/refreshing

Tags: redirect

I would like have to implement Ajax/J-Query for redirection one page to another page without refreshing.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you want to do? What have you tried? What is your code?

Answer (score 0):

ajax is not meant for redirection, you can update window.location from within a javascript function to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can download body html from server and then via js replace it with the current body. But usually refreshing page isn't bad thing if you need refresh all site content, not just the part. Ajax is not good for this because you'll got problems with history. And it doesn't work much faster. I you want to refresh just a part of a page - it is OK!